# Where is the bitcoin wedding transaction?

Tags: transactions

There has been some buzz in the news about a wedding that put a statement in the blockchain declaring their message. [Here](http://tucker.liberty.me/2014/09/25/blockchain_wedding/?refer=libertyme) is one source that reported on the news.

Can anyone provide a link to the actual transaction in a block explorer such as blockchain.info?

I'm looking for a link to an actual transaction in a block chain explorer that has the ASCII text in it that was described in the article, or an explanation of why one doesn't exist.

Comment: Somebody also did that a while ago using Datacoin (though I don't know whether there is currently an active Datacoin explorer where you can see it).

Comment: [This is the press release](http://blog.bitnation.co/2014/09/22/for-immediate-release-couple-to-get-married-on-the-bitcoin-blockchain-at-disney-bitcoin-conference/), but I can't find it either.

Comment: Considering adding a bounty to this question, really think this information should be available. It seems that it was done with BitNation, a counterparty application, but nowhere links to the actual transaction.

Answer (score 1):

[I think I found it](http://bigreport.io/worlds-first-wedding-blockchain/), although it doesn't have the text as advertised.

> History was made today when David Mondrus and Joyce Bayo tied the knot on the blockchain. The transaction took place through Eric Grill’s CoinOutlet ATM at Disney World. The couple ‘burned’ 0.1 Bitcoin, committing their marriage to the network. Jeffrey Tucker officiated the wedding with one of the most moving speeches you’ll ever hear.
>
> Here is the historic transaction ID: https://blockchain.info/tx/ad2e849f1de6d48dce1b671fe9b4ef6aee9c50710daccce3c0195087233ef2f6

Looking at the transaction history, it appears that they repeatedly made transactions until they spent 0.1 BTC. Ick.

Comment: Good find, but why doesn't the transaction have the text in it that they said it would? Seems strange that they had to do so many transactions, too.